# Is the inverse of f continuous

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I am not sure about III since in a general metric space, Heine-Borel doesn't hold. I found a closed set D in A and aimed to prove its image in f(A) is closed. But I couldn't get D compact hence couldn't conclude its image is compact. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not clear on whether you're asked to prove the three statements, or whether you're supposed to determine which are true

Comment: Also, what is the meaning of the *set* $f(A)$ being uniformly continuous?

Comment: II is false too. Take $tan $ on its usual domain for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

III is false.  The standard example is $X = \mathbb R$ and $Y = S^1$.  If we take $A = [0,1)$, then $$f: A \rightarrow Y$$ $$f(x) = e^{2\pi i x}$$

is a continuous bijection with $A$ bounded and $Y$ compact, but $f$ is not a homeomorphism.

Comment: Yes, this is true.

Comment: Very   nice +1....